# useSelector() return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I just learn react-native basic, and when work with redux, i have problem with `useSelector` , here is some of my code

Here is store component

```
//store.js
    initState = {
        loginStatus: false,
    }
    const LoginAction = (state = {initState}, action) => {
        if (action.type == 'changeLogin') {
            return { loginStatus:!state.loginStatus }
        }
        return state
    }
    const store = createStore(LoginAction, composeWithDevTools());
    export default store
```

Here is Login Function

```
function LoginScreen({ navigation, props }) {
 
 

     const dispatch = useDispatch()
      const Login = useSelector(state => {
        return state.LoginStatus
      })
    
      function getLogin() {
        return Login
      }
      function handleLogin() {
        dispatch({ type: 'changeLogin' })
      }
      console.log('Login ' + Login) // it return undefined
```

I have tried this method [useSelector state returns undefined (React-Redux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481217/useselector-state-returns-undefined-react-redux) but it didn't work!
Here is screenshot of what happened [image]

But when i add that to login button, it return true, then continute to undefined

```
<Formik
        validateOnMount
        validationSchema={loginValidationSchema}
        initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
        onSubmit={
          () => {
            handleLogin()
            console.log('When submit ' + Login) // true then undefined
            SetTimer();
          }
          // () => navigation.navigate('Login')
        }
      >
```

[image]

Please help , thank a lot

Comment: I'm not familiar with Formik, but does it preventDefault in the onSubmit handler behind the scenes? Because if it doesn't that means your browser window refreshes, losing its entire state.

Comment: I think it should be `const LoginAction = (state = initState)` instead of `const LoginAction = (state = {initState})`

Comment: about formik prevent default [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60705833/how-disable-the-auto-reset-form-on-submit-in-formik)

Comment: hey it work !!!!! @WebbH, but why ????????

Comment: i'm really don't know much about formik, but i guest it refresh all because, when i log a variable in formik it get loop

Answer (score 3):

The casing is wrong in your selector. It should be `return state.loginStatus`. Also, your `LoginAction` is technically a *reducer*, not an action.

```js
const Login = useSelector(state => {
  return state.loginStatus
})
```

Edit: An additional issue in the reducer is the initial state has `initState` as the top-level key in the object, when the intent is just for it to be assigned directly:

```js
const LoginAction = (state = initState, action) = {
  // reducer code here
}
```

Comment: yep, i will fix that, but problem fixed when i change `state={initState}` to `state=initState`, can you tell me what happened? i just learn react-native so i'm very curious

Comment: `state = {initState}` would mean `state = { initState: { loginStatus: false } }`. I'm assuming you don't want `initState` to actually be a top level key in your state. `state = initState` does what you want: `state = { loginStatus: false }`

Comment: so if i want to call it i'll use `state.initState.loginStatus` or something? i just curious how to use if i use `{ }` symbol

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Doesn't seem like that's what you would want though!

Comment: It show false at first, but when i click button it show error, like this https://ibb.co/Bnw5pQq . how can i fix to make it work with `state = { initState: { loginStatus: false } }` ,yes , it not my intention, but i just want to know deeper about redux, please help, thank you a lot

Comment: when i click it trigger dispatch, mean it active what `type==changeLogin` do, but it show error