# How to disable form submit on enter with useFormik?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I am building a form using *React*, *Typescript* and *Formik*. The form has three inputs. I want to prevent the form from submitting when the user presses enter in the input fields.

My first approach was using the `event.preventDefault()` statement, but that didn't work. Then I found [this solution here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67892964/9843082), but in this solution the [`Formik` component](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik) is used and not the [useFormik hook](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik).

So I wounder how to disable form submit on enter with useFormik?

Answer (score 1):

The `useFormik` hook provides a `handleSubmit` methods which handles that, pass it to your form `onSubmit` prop.

```
...
const fomrik = useFormik(...);

return (
  <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type='button'>Submit</button>
```

> type='button'

By using this, pressing enter would not trigger the form onSubmit .